# How to check is a dialog opened or not ?

Tags: android

I have static method in which i create a dialog

```
public static void showDialog(Context context) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle("Title");
    builder.setMessage("Message");
    builder.setPositiveButton("ok", new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }});
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.create().show();
}
```

In my app there is can be a situation when method can be called several times, but i don't want to open 2 or more dialogs. How to check is the dialog opened or not ? Thanks...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You should put this code in every activity that you want to support this feature.

```
public AlertDialog myAlertDialog;

public void showDialog(Context context) {
        if( myAlertDialog != null && myAlertDialog.isShowing() ) return;

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setTitle("Title");
        builder.setMessage("Message");
        builder.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }});
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        myAlertDialog = builder.create();
        myAlertDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: This approach won't work on different activities if you will pass `this` means `Activity` as a context. When the second activity will invoke this method, the context will be out-of-date (the first `Activity`).

Comment: @user639183 You are right. It is best to put this in the activity class and make it not static.

Comment: for me that can works...In my app only one Activity can call this method for few times. But I don't like to work with static members...Is that safe ? Should I kill this member ?

Comment: if( myAlertDialog == null .... Why we check for null ? Here should be != null... No ?

Comment: 0_0 why did you make this method static if you have only 1 activity? you should go like `public void showDialog()` and pass `this` to the builder

Comment: I have 10 activities that can call this method...But only 1 Activity can call it several times...

Comment: @Jim I have updated the code. Now it is not static, but you should copy this code in every activity to support this feature. The check for myAlertDialog == null is needed, because the first time myAlertDialog will be null and we have to create one.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your method to return `AlertDialog`, assign it to a member and check before invoking this method if it's null or `!isShowing()`.
You could also use `onCreateDialog` instead. Implement this method in base class for your activities that needs the dialog managing and then call `showDialog(int id)` wherever you want.

Comment: this method will not run the same dialog several times ?

Comment: It will attempt to, if you won't check for `null` and `isShowing`

Answer (score -1):

```
            AlertDialog alertDialog;
    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle(title);
    alertDialog.setMessage(msg);        
    alertDialog.setButton(-3, "Text Parsed", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: you can pass title, msg dynamically from the function on top!

Comment: The asker wanted to know about checking if a dialog is active or not. This does not answer that question.